# Integrating Clang Within NetBeans?

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, ide, clang

What are the steps involved in integrating Clang within NetBeans? I would like to also see the Clang error and warning messages from within NetBeans. This will be used mainly for developing in C.

Comment: this is more about netbeans than llvm/clang. I am also interested in this.

Answer (score 11):

NetBeans 7.2 has supported Clang natively.

Just open up Options Window, switch to C/C++ section, and add a new Tool Collection. Type:  `/usr/bin` in Base Directory, and select "CLang" in the combo box.

I have been using Clang to build my project, and NetBeans works with Clang perfectly.

Comment: @StellarVortex Wherever you install your LLVM toolchain, use the directory containing `clang.exe` as the "Base Directory".

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=194166) is a link to the bug report for clang support in netbeans at [netbeans.org](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=194166). Track this bug for official netbeans support.

Comment: its current status is TBD (to-be-decided)

Answer (score 1):

If you have downloaded and installed the C/C++ plug-in for NetBeans 8+ following the instructions on this page:

https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/cpp-setup-instructions.html

you have a C/C++ item in the upper menu of the Tools > Options panel. 1.) Click it.

2.) Now under the list called "Tool Collection" (on the left) click the left button "Add".

3.) In the window that opens, enter the "/usr/bin" as a base directory.

4.) If you have a CLang compiler installed right the "Tool Collection Family" drop-down menu will show a CLang collection. Choose it.

5.) Click "OK" in the pop-up window, then click "OK" in the "Options" panel/window.

Enjoy.