# How to let llvm-clang work with netbeans

Tags: c, linux, netbeans, llvm, clang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integrating Clang Within NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241862/integrating-clang-within-netbeans)

Is it possible to use llvm-clang with netbeans in linux?

now, I only can config it with llvm-gcc, how to config it with clang?

thanks!

Comment: What does `./configure --help` or `./configure -h` say?

Comment: If you were able to make Netbeans work with llvm-gcc, can you descrie what problems you face when configuring it with clang?